# ASP.NET - Storing Common Accessed Data e.g. Settings, Current User etc

Tags: asp.net

Everywhere in my application i often have to grab the same information (current logged in user) and declare the same services (authorization, settings etc). So far i have combated this problem by doing the following in my Global.asax file:

```
public class App : HttpApplication {
    private static IMembershipService _membershipService;
    public static IAuthorizationService Authorization;
    public static ISettingsService Settings;

    public static User CurrentUser {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? _membershipService.GetUser(((UserIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Id) : null; }
    }

    protected void Application_Start() {
        // Create the ioc container
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        ... Register Types Here

        _membershipService = container.Resolve<IMembershipService>();
        Authorization = container.Resolve<IAuthorizationService>();
        Settings = container.Resolve<ISettingsService>();
    }
}
```

Now to access the current logged in user i simply have to say App.CurrentUser. Note although it is declared static the get is not cached into a static variable and therefore it is different for each request.

I was just wondering if this is a good solution. There's something i don't like about it but i'd appreciate the opinions of some ASP.NET experts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an abuse of the static keyword, especially since you are using an IoC container.

assuming this is an MVC app you should only need a very limited number of calls to the container. The primary call would be the controller factory that would resolve the controller from the container. there may be a few other places to call the continer, but ideally only one.

if this is webforms you could setup a base class with protected read-only properties to resolve components in the ctor or page_init event. not ideal, but a step in the right direction.

the other thing to consider is that static classes imply singletons. in which case the components cannot have state. otherwise you get into all kinds of bugs with shared state and race conditions.

I find it's best to using transient objects as much as possible, and only keep them around for a short time. lower memory consumption and the object can be tailored to the context in which it's used.

Comment: Hi thanks for the recommendation. I have now removed the services from this class and have stored the user within a session.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that all of that code belongs outside of `Global.asax`, preferably in a class dedicated to user management. A `UserManager` class, if you will. The only thing that should be in your `Global.asax` is a method call in `Application_Start` to create your IOC containers.

But that's a style issue, not an issue with the approach. The approach itself is fine. I personally would not return null for User; I would stick with the `HttpContext.Current.User` approach of returning an anonymous entity user class. But again, that's a style issue.

The only worry I have is that the `Service` post-fixed classes are actually WCF proxies, which should (probably) be short-lived objects rather than something maintained across all requests. If I'm misreading your code, ignore this whole paragraph. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The services are simply classes which allow me to encapsulate the database logic and possibly cache it.